# Table with minumum frequency

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements

I have got a vector of numbers and I only want to keep all entries occuring with a minumum frequency:

```
set.seed(1)

min <- 3

vec <- rpois(20, 1)
vec
#> 0 1 1 2 0 2 3 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 4 1 2

table(vec)
#> vec
#> 0 1 2 3 4 
#> 5 9 4 1 1
```

In this case, I want to discard the 3's and 4's and only keep the 0's, 1's and 2's since they occur more than 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `ave`

```
vec[ave(vec, vec, FUN = length) > min]
#[1] 0 1 1 2 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `i1` is your `table`

```
i1 <- table(vec)
vec[vec %in% names(i1)[i1 > min]]
#[1] 0 1 1 2 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
```